# Function AddFontResourceEx does not work properly in the WinAPI project

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, ansi

I work on my own WinAPI project and use ANSI version of API language C/C++ but I have faced with the issue when I running the program on computer with non-Russian version windows. I see unreadable symbols instead of russian letters.

I try to use method AddFontResourceEx and on Russian version Windows it works correctly but when I run on non-Russian version Windows I have got an error "Font 1 Error" and  I see unreadable symbols.
How can I solve this issue?

Font "MY_ARIAL.TTF" is in the folder with exe-file

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static LOGFONT lf1; 

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

         if(AddFontResourceEx("MY_ARIAL.TTF", FR_PRIVATE, NULL)!=0)
         {
             SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE,0,0);
             lstrcpy((LPSTR)&lf1.lfFaceName, "My_Arial");           
         }
         else       
             MessageBox(hWnd,"Font 1 Error","error",MB_OK);  
    }
}
```

Comment: *and use ANSI version* - There's your problem. Always use the wide versions of winapi functions unless you plan on supporting a version of Windows that's almost two decades old, in which case you should use `TCHAR`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static LOGFONT lf1 = {0}; 

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

         if (AddFontResourceEx(TEXT("MY_ARIAL.TTF"), FR_PRIVATE, NULL))
         {
             SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
             lstrcpy(lf1.lfFaceName, TEXT("My_Arial"));
         }
         else       
             MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Font 1 Error"), TEXT("error"), MB_OK);  
    }
}
```

Or:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static LOGFONTW lf1 = {0}; 

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

         if (AddFontResourceExW(L"MY_ARIAL.TTF", FR_PRIVATE, NULL))
         {
             SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
             lstrcpyW(lf1.lfFaceName, L"My_Arial");
         }
         else       
             MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Font 1 Error", L"error", MB_OK);  
    }
}
```

Either way, keep in mind that you are specifying a *relative* path to `AddFontResourceEx()`, so it is subject to whatever path [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx) returns, which **MAY NOT** be what you are expecting!  **NEVER** use a *relative* path, **ALWAYS** use an *absolute* path instead.  You can retrieve your app's folder using `GetModuleFileName()` and then remove the filename portion (everything after the last `'\'` character).  Then you can append `"MY_ARIAL.TTF"` to that and pass the whole thing to `AddFontResourceEx()`.  Look at [`PathRemoveFileSpec()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) and [`PathCombine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx) for that.